# J4. Showing a Popover in field label

Tags: joomla-4.x, bootstrap

In J3, xml field attributes label and description appears (language converted) as popover when class hasPopover is included. In J4 only label is rendered but not description in a popover. Adding data-bs-content="COM_MYCOMPONENT_FIELD_DESCRIPTION" as xml property, the popover is shown but language is unconverted.

Is there a way to render description attribute in a popover like J3 do? Or it's neccesary remove it from xml field and include it hardcoded in defalt.php?

**forms/espacio.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form addfieldprefix="Sfi\Component\Aaprueba\Site\Field">

    <fieldset>

        <field 
            name="espacio" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control hasPopover"
            label="COM_AAPRUEBA_FIELD_ESPACIO_LBL" 
            description="COM_AAPRUEBA_FIELD_ESPACIO_DESC" 
        />
```

**src/View/Espacio/HtmlView.php**

```
...
use Joomla\CMS\Form\FormHelper;
...
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $this->item     = $this->get('Item');
        $this->form     = $this->get('Form');
        
        HTMLHelper::_('bootstrap.popover', '.hasPopover,[data-bs-toggle="popover"]', ['trigger' => 'hover']);
...
```

**tmpl/espacio/default.php**

```
...
// description is not shown
<?= $this->form->getLabel('espacio'); ?>
<?= $this->form->getInput('espacio'); ?>
...

// Alternative method. Popover is shown but this solutiom is less clean than before
<span class="hasPopover" 
    data-bs-original-title="<?= Text::_('COM_AAPRUEBA_FIELD_ESPACIO_LBL') ?>" 
    data-bs-content="<?= Text::_('COM_AAPRUEBA_FIELD_ESPACIO_DESC') ?>"
    >
    <?= $this->form->getLabel('espacio'); ?>
</span>
            
<?= $this->form->getInput('espacio'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In J3 the popovers in form fields were rendered in `layouts/joomla/form/renderlabel.php` layout. In J4, instead of popovers, an inline description is shown. It's rendered by `layouts/joomla/form/renderfield.php` layout. To use popovers in all your fields in your component you can make component level override of the `renderlabel` layout and the logic for rendering popovers there. And to prevent duplicate description from being shown, create an override of `renderfield` layout and remove the inline description there.

To create component level overrides, place them in `administrator/components/com_example/layouts/joomla/form` directory.

Comment: Using `$this->form->renderField('fieldname');` rather than combination `getLabel() + getInput.` I don't need to show descriptions in all fields, and your solution open new ways. Thank you.